# C# Script in SSIS Crashing when Using RestSharp Library

Tags: c#, ssis

I'm trying to run this in an SSIS script task:

```
#region Namespaces
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using RestSharp;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using WinSCP;
#endregion

namespace ST_a949541a7e9d41c2b7ae8d402e8adb24
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
        public void Main()
        {
            string requestUrl = "www.google.com";
            var client = new RestClient(requestUrl);

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
    }
}
```

Making use of the RestSharp net4 library.  It appears to build / compile fine, but then when I try to run my package I get these errors on my script task:

```
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()
```

I've executed the exact same code with the same library in a non-SSIS project and it works.  What is happening here?

Comment: Usually you need to install those libraries into the GAC but there's a work around that can help you https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dbrowne/2014/06/25/how-to-load-an-assembly-in-a-ssis-script-task-that-isnt-in-the-gac/

Comment: So, I had been doing this previously, and it had been working at that point, but I was annoyed by the fact that every time I would edit the script I would have to re-install the libraries with NuGet, just to appease VS.  I thought I found out how I could utilize the DLLs by adding direct references to them and not having them in the GAC, but apparently not.  And now I can't even get this to work again either... getting the same error.